# Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent. With chunkedApply() function

Tags: r

I want to divide the rows of my data into chunks using function `chunkedApply` from package **BGData**. I have tried:

```r
library(BGData)
library(parallel)

subset <- Merged_Data[1:50, 1:50] # just subsetting the data

n <- 4L
index <- splitIndices(nrow(subset), n)

for (k in seq_len(n)) {
    chunk <- chunkedApply(subset, MARGIN = 1L, FUN = identity, i = index[[k]])
    print(length(chunk))
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

Why am I seeing this error? How can I resolve it?

EDIT: I think the error is in the 'identity' function. Because when I run the above code with FUN = length, then everything works properly.

Comment: What kind of object is `Merged_Data`? A matrix? What is the output of `str(Merged_Data)`?

Comment: @MikaelJagan Merged_Data is a ColumnLinkedMatrix object. I did a subset of Merged_Data, becasue the file is quite big. str(subset) returns this: int [1:50, 1:50] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:50] "100812" "100813" "AANAUSF000000AG0149" "AANAUSF000000AG0150" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:50] "1_695_G_A_A" "1_1445_C_T_T" "1_1475_A_T_T" "1_1478_T_C_C" ...

Comment: Seems like your `subset` is a simple matrix, not a "file-backed matrix", which is what `?chunkedApply` expects.